# Probability of Non-Matching Colors in Stacked Book Piles.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

*Three orange books, three blue books, and three green books are randomly stacked to form three piles of three books each.
What is the probability that no book will be the same color as the book directly above it?*

Using a decision tree in excel I found that the probability is 1/5. The R code below gives the same result.

```
library(MASS)
library(RcppAlgos)
library(magrittr)

permuteGeneral(c("A", "B", "C"), freqs = c(3, 3, 3), FUN = \(x) {
  if (x[1] != x[2] && x[2] != x[3] && x[4] != x[5] && x[5] != x[6] &&
    x[7] != x[8] && x[8] != x[9]) {
    TRUE
  } else {
    FALSE
  }
})  %>% unlist() %>% {fractions(sum(.)/length(.))}
```

But surely there must be a more elegant solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how "elegant" this is:

There are $\frac {9!}{(3!)^3}=1680$ ways to arrange the books with no color restrictions (assuming the stacks are labeled).

One way to satisfy the color rule is to have three different colors in each stack.  As you can sort a single such stack in $6$ ways, there are $6^3=216$ such patterns.

Now suppose that one of the stacks in a good arrangement is of the form $XYX$.  That leaves $\{X,Y,Y,Z,Z,Z\}$.  The three $Z's$ require that one of the other stacks is $ZXZ$ or $ZYZ$, the other is then $YZY$ in the first case or some permutation of $XYZ$ in the second.  Let's count these arrangements:

I.  The stacks are $XYX, ZXZ, YZY$.  First we must order the stacks.  Without loss of generality, we may assume that the first stack is $XYX$.  But then it makes a different which stack is second, choosing that gives a factor of $2$.  After that, the order is determined and there are $6$ ways to assign colors to the letters, so there are $12$ such arrangements.

II.  The stacks are $XYX, ZYZ$ and some permutation of $XYZ$.  Note that the stacks themselves can be permuted.  Pick the $XYZ$ stack, three choices for the stack and six permutations, hence $18$ ways to do that.  Now you are left with $XYX, ZYZ$....three ways to assign the $Y$ and then two choices for the others, hence $6$ ways to assign these.  That makes $18\times 6=108$ such arrangements.

Altogether, then, we have $108+12=120$ good arrangements of this type.

That makes for $120+216=336$ good arrangements in total.

And $$\frac {336}{1680}=\frac 15$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is my reasoning. Let there be three different piles with three books in every pile. That gives nine positions for the books. So the whole number of various arrangements of these books equals to $9!/(3!)^3$ since we don’t differentiate the books of the same colour

Now, let us find the number of arrangements when the similar books don’t stack one above the other. There are three major groups of arrangements:

(1) All the books are different colour in every pile

(2) One pile has two books of the same colour. Assume the pile looks like 121, where 1 and 2 are some colours. What happens to colour 2 in the second pile? The second pile can look like 123 (and the third one is 323 then)…

(3) … or it looks like 232 (and the third pile is 313 then)

So the piles look like this in every case:

(1) 123 123 123

(2) 121 123 323

(3) 121 232 313

It’s quite easy to find the number of arrangements for every case now:

(1) $(3!)^3$

(2) $3 \cdot 3! \cdot 3 \cdot 2$

(3) $3! \cdot 2$

Now, we get the answer: $((3!)^3 + 3 \cdot 3! \cdot 3 \cdot 2 + 3! \cdot 2) / (9!/(3!)^3)) = 1/5$